# How to mock document in Jest and find meta tags?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function where I set my document title & description & and I need write a test.

func.js

```
const setMetaTags = function() {
  document.title = "brandName";
  const description = document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]');

  if (description) {
    description.setAttribute('content', 'text text text text');
  }
};
```

test.js

```
import sum from './func.js';

describe('testFunc', () => {
  it('should test something', () => {
    const spyFunc = setMetaTags();


    Object.defineProperty(global.document, 'meta[name="description"]', { value: ?? });
  });
});
```

???

Comment: Have you considered using the [`globals`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object) object in Jest to provide a mock for `document`?

Comment: Do you mean it ? `Object.defineProperty(global, 'document', {});`

Comment: Yes, that can work. Just be careful that you'll probably also need to mock `querySelector` and ensure the returned mock object also has a `setAttribute` mock available (i.e. with `jest.fn()`).

Comment: Can you write an example or send link? I don't understand how to check existence `title` & `description` in my function. Thanks.